# What is the extended events equivalent of the default sys trace security audit events?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, extended-events, trace

I am exploring the default sys trace and it contains various records for the security changes on the SQL server (event record examples are shown in screenshot below).

Since the trace feature can be removed in a future SQL version, is there an extended events equivalent that captures this by default (for example in the system health extended events)? Or does this need setting up?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

System_health doesn't capture those specific events. You can look at what it does capture. It has the connectivity_ring_buffer_event which does include quite a few of the actions above, plus failed login attempts. However, that's about it in system_health. There's not much in the way of security audit within extended events.

Instead of extended events, if you're interested in security auditing, SQL Server has created a much more extensive audit system through security audit. [You can read all about it here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/database-administration-sql-server/sql-server-security-audit-basics/). It does all of those events, plus a whole bunch more.

Comment: Ok so extended events default system health doesn't have those events logged but I can configure a new extended event session to have these events? Or server audit is the only solution?

Comment: Server audit is the solution. They simply didn't migrate those events into Extended Events since they were part of server audit.